# Conflicting gem dependencies for the same gem. ruby depends on refinerycms-core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, refinerycms

I created a new app in Refinery CMS and followed the instructions according to their guide. http://refinerycms.com/download

But when I go to run rails server, I get errors about gem dependencies. Normally those are easy to fix. But what to do when you have conflicting dependencies? This is one of the errors that I got

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "refinerycms-core":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms-blog (~> 2.0.0) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-core (~> 2.0.0) ruby

    refinerycms (~> 2.1.0) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-core (2.1.0)
```

when I have ran into this problem in the past and I added the specific gem, it then would still give me an error saying that it needed the other gem as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I also met these problems before. I think specifying a version of a gem is needed in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a response on Twitter from the people at refinery who sent me this link

https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2386#issuecomment-22978992

which says so change the gem to

```
gem 'refinerycms-blog', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-blog', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: This is because refinerycms-blog 2.0.0 wants refinerycms 2.0.0 but you've specified refinerycms 2.1.0 so the github source will use refinerycms-blog 2.1.0 which is currently unreleased.